# How to install firetools in whonix?

Tags: repository, whonix, firejail

My goal to launch browser safety, for this task I need use firejail (exists in backports repository) and firetools (not exists in main and in backports).

Are there any ways install firetools on whonix distributive?

Information [I've found](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Dev/Firejail) about it is only:

> Firetools is in sid and stretch only but its dependencies will create a mess even with pinning.